# FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 20, current size 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

My code is here. I'm using python 3.6.2. Each folder has 100 images named for example negativa_peaton_1, negativa_peaton_2 until negativa_peaton_100 in no folder case.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image
from six.moves import xrange


# config
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 100
num_examples = 1000
num_train = int(0.8*num_examples)
num_test = int(0.2*num_examples)

IMAGE_WIDTH  = 40
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 80
IMAGE_DEPTH  = 1
IMAGE_PIXELS = IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT
NUM_CLASSES  = 2
BATCH_SIZE    = 20

# function to read image names
def read_my_list( minId, maxId, folder ):


    filenames = []
    labels    = []
    for num in range( minId, maxId+1 ):

        filenames.append( "/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo" + folder + "/si/" + name_si( num ) + ".jpg" )
        labels.append( int( 1 ) )

        filenames.append( "/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo" + folder + "/no/" + name_no( num ) + ".jpg" )
        labels.append( int( 0 ) )

        print( num_name(num) )

    # return list with all filenames
    print( "number of labels: " + str( len( labels ) ) )
    print( "number of images: " + str( len( filenames ) ) )
    return filenames, labels

def num_name( id ):



    ret = str( id )
    while ( len( ret ) < 5 ):
        ret = "0" + ret;

    return ret;

def name_si( id ):

    ret = str( id )
    ret = "peaton_" + ret;

    return ret;

def name_no( id ):

    ret = str( id )
    ret = "negativa_peaton_" + ret;

    return ret;

# read and prepare images
def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):

    label = input_queue[1]
    print( "read file "  )
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    example = tf.image.decode_jpeg( file_contents, channels = 1 )
    print(example)
    example = tf.image.resize_images(example,[IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])
    print(example)
    example = tf.reshape( example, [ IMAGE_PIXELS ] )
    print(example)
    example.set_shape( [ IMAGE_PIXELS ] )
    print(example)

    example = tf.cast( example, tf.float32 )
    example = tf.cast( example, tf.float32 ) * ( 1. / 255 ) - 0.5

    label = tf.cast( label, tf.int64 )

    label = tf.one_hot( label, 2, 0, 1 )
    label = tf.cast( label, tf.float32 )

    print( "file read " )
    return  example, label

def fill_feed_dict(image_batch, label_batch, imgs, lbls):
  feed_dict = {
      imgs: image_batch,
      lbls: label_batch,
  }
  return feed_dict

# input images
# None -> batch size can be any size, IMAGE_PIXELS -> image size
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMAGE_PIXELS], name="x-input")
# target 2 output classes
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_CLASSES], name="y-input")

# model parameters will change during training so we use tf.Variable
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([IMAGE_PIXELS, NUM_CLASSES]))

# bias
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASSES]))

# implement model
# y is our prediction
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

# specify cost function
# this is our cost --> y is the net output, y_ is the target
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

# Accuracy --> y is the net output, y_ is the target
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# specify optimizer
# optimizer is an "operation" which we can execute in a session
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

# DATA FOR TRAINING
# get filelist and labels for training (num_train/2 examples of each class)
image_list, label_list = read_my_list( 1, int(num_train/2), "train" )

# create queue for training
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer( [ image_list, label_list ])

# read files for training
image, label = read_images_from_disk( input_queue )

# `image_batch` and `label_batch` represent the "next" batch
# read from the input queue.
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch( [ image, label ], batch_size = BATCH_SIZE )

# DATA FOR TESTING
# get filelist and labels for tESTING
image_list_test, label_list_test = read_my_list( int(num_train/2)+1, int(num_examples/2), "train" )

# create queue for training
input_queue_test = tf.train.slice_input_producer( [ image_list_test, label_list_test ])

# read files for training
image_test, label_test = read_images_from_disk( input_queue_test )

# read from the input queue.
image_batch_test, label_batch_test = tf.train.batch( [ image_test, label_test ], batch_size = num_test )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # variables need to be initialized before we can use them
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    # perform training cycles
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):

        # number of batches in one epoch
        batch_count = int(num_train/BATCH_SIZE)

        for i in range(batch_count):

            imgs, lbls = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch])

            sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={x:imgs, y_:lbls})

        print("Epoch: ", epoch)
        imgs_test, lbls_test = sess.run([image_batch_test, label_batch_test])
        print ("Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: imgs_test , y_: lbls_test}))
    print ("done")
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

I got this probrem

2017-10-12 00:25:19.457738: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-12 00:25:19.457845: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
8
2017-10-12 00:25:19.806878: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\queue_base.cc:295] _3_batch_1/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
2017-10-12 00:25:19.807235: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\queue_base.cc:295] _2_input_producer_1/input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
2017-10-12 00:25:19.811144: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\queue_base.cc:295] _0_input_producer/input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in **exit**
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
         [[Node: Variable_1/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NeuralNet_L1.py", line 176, in 
    sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={x:imgs, y_:lbls})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
         [[Node: Variable_1/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Caused by op 'Variable_1/read', defined at:
  File "NeuralNet_L1.py", line 113, in 
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_CLASSES]))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 199, in **init**
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 330, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1400, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in **init**
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
         [[Node: Variable_1/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates cause of the problem:

> 2017-10-11 22:52:23.533465: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: /Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplotrain/si/peaton_457.jpg : El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

There is no file named `"/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplotrain/si/peaton_457.jpg"`. At a guess, I would say that the path is being constructed incorrectly, and should be `"/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo/train/si/peaton_457.jpg"` (with a `/` between `Ejemplo` and `train`).

To avoid this kind of problem, use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of string concatenation to build paths:

```
for num in range( minId, maxId+1 ):

    filenames.append(os.path.join(
        "/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo",
        folder, "si", name_si(num) + ".jpg")
    labels.append(int(1))

    filenames.append(
        "/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo",
        folder, "no", name_no( num ) + ".jpg")
    labels.append(int(0))

    print(num_name(num))
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the new full error message?

Comment: Do the files `"/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo/train/no/negativa_peaton_379.jpg"` and `"/Users/RetailAdmin/Documents/Inteligencia Artificial/Python/Ejemplo/train/si/peaton_427.jpg"` exist on your computer? Is it possible that they are on a different drive (and in that case, you should include the drive letter, such as `"C:"` at the beginning of the path)?

Comment: I fixed that and a new problem comes up

Comment: Add a call to `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` right after you create the Session.